# Laravel Request Validation: Check if time is between two times?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a input of type `time` inside my view, which accepts a minimum value of `09:00` and a maximum value of `18:00`.

```
<input type="time" name="time_event" required="" min="09:00" max="18:00">
```

In this case, the user can enter several different times like `09:43`, `10:58`, `17:33`... but as long as the time starts from `09:00` and goes until `18:00`.

With that in mind I have a validation rule with Laravel:

```
'time_event' => 'required|date_format:H:i|between:09,18',
```

The problem is that the `between rule` is not working correctly.

How can I validate with laravel if the time type field is within the standards required by my system?

Comment: No idea about laravel, but you could explode on the colon, cast to int, multiply the hours by 60, add the minutes, then check if the input type is between `9*60` and `18*60`

Comment: If nothing else works you could still create a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Answer (score 1):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function validateTime(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'time_event' => ['required', 'date_format:H:i', 'after:08:59', 'before:18:01'],
    ]);
}
```

Try this

Comment: Hi, while your answer may address the question, it'better to include some [explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers)